# QList <int> replace value

Tags: qt, qlist

I have QList of int.

```
eg: [10,10];
```

Then I want to reduce the value by 1.

I tried:

```
foreach (int val, valList) {
    val-= 1;
}
```

But qDebug of valList shows their values remain as 10. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this with C++ 11 and later:

```
void changeIntVals(QList<int>& valList)
{
   for(auto& val: valList)
   {
      val -= 1;
   }
}
```

P.S. Have not tried to compile.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `foreach` for changing the values within the container you are iterating over as [the official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword) says:

> Qt automatically takes a copy of the container when it enters a
>   foreach loop. If you modify the container as you are iterating, that
>   won't affect the loop. (If you do not modify the container, the copy
>   still takes place, but thanks to implicit sharing copying a container
>   is very fast.)
>
> Since foreach creates a copy of the container, using a non-const
>   reference for the variable does not allow you to modify the original
>   container. It only affects the copy, which is probably not what you
>   want.
>
> An alternative to Qt's foreach loop is the range-based for that is
>   part of C++ 11 and newer. However, keep in mind that the range-based
>   for might force a Qt container to detach, whereas foreach would not.
>   But using foreach always copies the container, which is usually not
>   cheap for STL containers. If in doubt, prefer foreach for Qt
>   containers, and range based for for STL ones.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go.